# fixing a value at the first loop-R

Tags: r, for-loop

I think this is a simple problem. But I am stuck.

Let I have the below code:

```
for(k:1:5){     
 z=sqrt(k) 
 m=k*z
}
```

I just want to lock z=sqrt(1), I mean in each iteration I want z to be equal to sqrt(1).

But,while doing that I dont want to use z=sqrt(1). I want z be assigned to sqrt(k) at the first iteration and then at each loop I want it to be fix.

My original problem of much comlex. But solution to this problem will solve my original problem.

The loop should precess as below:

```
for k=1;  z=1, m=1*1=1
for k=2;  z=1, m=2*1=1
for k=3;  z=1, m=3*1=1
for k=4;  z=1, m=4*1=1
for k=5;  z=1, m=5*1=1
```

As above, z will be 1 which for each iteration, assigned at its value at the first iteration.

Comment: [XY problem?](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: When you say first iteration, is this for loop going into another loop.  If that is the case your condition should be on top of this

Comment: @akrun, I edited the question. Maybe it may be more clear now.

Comment: if that is the case, why can't you create the `z` outside the loop i.e. `v1 <- 1:5;z <- v1[1]; for(k %in% v1) {m <- k * z}`

Comment: @akrun, my original code is much more complicated, the value of z should be calculated inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` condition

```
v1 <- 1:5

for(k in seq_along(v1)){  
if(k == 1) {
  z <<- sqrt(v1[k]) 
  } 

 m <- v1[k]*z
 print(m)
}
```

Comment: this is not the result what I want. The result for this pobolem should be 1,2,3,4,5 for each iteration. Because z should be fixed to 1 at the fisrt iteration and it shouldn't be change at the other iterations.

Comment: @oercim in your loop, is it possible to create an object outside and then loop over the sequence of that object.  then ,my update should work

Comment: @oercim I meant `z <<- sqrt(v1[k])` , there was a typo.  In the present example, it doesn't matter because it was looping from 1 onwards

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use another variable like `z_fixed`? you can fix it outside the loop. This way you can keep z as well.
Otherwise, if you really want to fix it inside, create another variable `first_iter` outside the loop and use it this way:

```
first_iter <- TRUE
for(k:1:5){  
 if (first_iter) z <- sqrt(k); firs_iter <- FALSE
 m=k*z
}
```